# Drawable inside Button is getting enlarged

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button, android-drawable

For some reason, I need to use a button with both icon and text. So I can't use `ImageButton` and thus I go for a solution to set the `drawableTop` of a normal `Button`.

The `Button` size is 140dp in square shape (please refer to the screenshot below)

The I was planning to use was 125x125 px and the asset itself is clear and crisp.

However, this 125px asset somehow being enlarged by the button, like the screenshot shown below.

The device is an xhdpi device.

As you can see, the icon inside the square button is blurry which looks like being somehow enlarged

[image]

Here I pasted my button XML

```
<Button
                android:id="@+id/button_call_us"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="140dp"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/main_menu_button_margin"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
                android:drawablePadding="-20dp"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/button_call_us_icon"
                android:lines="2"
                android:paddingTop="0dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:text="CALL US"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="6pt" />
```

The `android:background="@drawable/custom_button"` is the purple colour background without any patterns.

The `android:drawableTop="@drawable/button_call_us_icon"` is the icon.

Except `android:scaleType="fitXY"`, I have also tried `centerInside` and other options, still not getting the ideal result.
My question is:

Why the drawable inside a `Button` being enlarged? Is there any way to stop it?

Thanks

Comment: Can you display what you want? One thought is to use a TextView instead.

Comment: @PeterK. Hi, I've updated my questions, would u pls have a look? cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a button, and you want a drawable inside the button. Your probable solution would be to use an `ImageButton` which actually implements drawable properties. You can then call `android:scaleType="fitCenter"` and set some padding too

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/android_button" />
```

However, to get more freedom in terms of desing, you could use a simple layout instead of the button, something on the lines of this, just treat the `LinearLayout` as you would with a button, in terms of adding the onclicklistener:

```
<LinearLayout android:orientations="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#CCC"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:gravity="center">
    <ImageView android:src='@drawable/ic_launcher'
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView android:text="Lorem Ipsum"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Juan, thx for the advice. If I switch to using `ImageButton`, there will not be an easy way to add a line of text below the icons. Is there any way to do that by using `ImageButton` only? cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Drawable img = getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.img );
                img.setBounds( 0, 0, (int)(img.getIntrinsicWidth()), 
                         (int)(img.getIntrinsicHeight()) );
                button.setCompoundDrawables(null, img, null, null);
```